# воспроизведение gif только при помощи javascript

Tags: php, javascript

здравствуйте, вообщем хочу сделать воспроизведение гиф, думаю всем понятно о чем идет речь, есть статическая картинка, на ней иконка Play и при нажатии src меняется на гифку. я знаю как это сделать на php+js создавая заранее статичное изображение, но хотел бы узнать можно ли сделать это на чистом js/jq имя только gif картинку? чтобы не создавать каждый раз на пыхе jpeg изображение

Comment: Делать это клиентом не разумно. Вот когда все браузеры будут работать на webkit, тогда пожалуйста. А сейчас вы от этого поимеете больше проблем, чем пользы. Да и вообще не понятно зачем это нужно? Клиент каждый раз, при загрузке страницы, будет выдёргивать первый кадр из gif?

Comment: @vihtor да, мне нужно это чтобы не напрягать пых каждый раз создавая ненужную картинку

Comment: Зачем каждый раз? Это можно сделать один раз, и потом уже каждый раз отдавать ранее выдернутую картинку.

Comment: @vihtor я понимаю но я бы хотел это сделать чисто на JS, если такого решения нет то ладно

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите purejs-решение, пожалуйста. Надеюсь вы не расчитывали что оно будет простым. В данном случае я использовал библиотеку [gif-frames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gif-frames), но её работа (на клиенте?) приводит к артефактам.

Ну и на последок снова прочту вам *Отче наш*: Никто не занимается такими вещами на клиенте и причин тому несколько:

1. Потребность писать кроссбраузерный скрипт т.к. браузеров множество, как и клиентских реализаций JavaScript. Добиться работоспособности такого кода на всех и вся будет проблематично.
2. Клиент будет выполнять этот код каждый раз при загрузке страницы.
3. Трафик: клиент будет качать тяжелый gif-файл, только для того что бы увидеть его превью. Для мобильных устройств это веский аргумент.
4. Высока вероятность "повесить" пользовательский клиент на таких вычислениях.
5. Сервер проделает эту операцию один раз и закеширует результат. Далее клиент будет качать это превью и, только при необходимости, весь gif.

```js
var $file = document.querySelector('#file'),
    $frames = document.querySelector('#frames'),
    $type = document.querySelector('#type'),
    $output = document.querySelector('.output'),
    $extract = document.querySelector('#extract');

/**
 * Конвертирует тип File в строку base64
 * @see https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64
 * @param {File} file
 * @param {Function} callback
 */
function fileToBase64(file, callback) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function onload() { callback(reader.result); };
  reader.onerror = function onerror(error) { alert('Error: ', error); };
}

/**
 * Извлечёт указанные кадры
 * @param {File} file Файл gif-анимации
 * @param {String} frames перечисление кадров
 * @param {string} mime тип изображения (по умолчанию image/png)
 * @param {Function} callback
 */
function extractFrames(file, frames, mime, callback) {
  // начала нужно сконвертировать файл в base64
  fileToBase64(file, function(data){

    // опции для gif-frames
    var options = {
      // ссылка на файл. Т.к. файл загружается не по ссылке
      // а выбирается пользователем, мы привели файл к ссылке
      url: data,
      frames: frames, // кадры для извлечения
      outputType: 'canvas' // тип результата
    };

    // вызов функции библиотеки gif-frames
    gifFrames(options, function(error, data){
      var $canvas,
          $image,
          result = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $canvas = data[0].getImage(); // извлекаем результат в виде html-элемента canvas
        $image = new Image(); // создаём пустое изображение
        $image.src = $canvas.toDataURL(mime); // извлекаем изобажение из canvas

        result.push({
          $canvas: $canvas,
          element: $image,
          width: $canvas.width,
          height: $canvas.height
        });
      }

      // возвращаем результат
      callback(result);
    });
  });
}

// при клике на кнопку "Извлечь"
$extract.addEventListener('click', function(){

  // выбираем всю неоходимую информацию введённую
  // в поля формы
  var file = $file.files[0],
      frames = $frames.value,
      type = $type.value;

  // проверка введённых данных
  if (file instanceof File === false || file.type !== 'image/gif') {
    alert('Необходимо выбрать GIF-файл');
    $file.click();
    return;
  }

  if (!frames) {
    alert('Укажите какие кадры нужно извлечь из анимации\nФормат: 1, 2-4, 5, 6)');
    $frames.focus();
    return;
  }

  // вызов функции извлекающей кадры
  extractFrames(file, frames, type, function(images){

    // очистка списка изображений
    $output.innerHTML = '';

    // перебираем извлечённые кадры
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      var image = images[i],
          $item = document.createElement('li'),
          $element = image.element;

      // меняем размер картинки
      $element.width = 200;
      $element.height = 200 / (image.width / image.height);

      // выгружаем данные в DOM
      $item.appendChild($element);
      $output.appendChild($item);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.controls {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.control {
  padding: 10px;
}

.control > label {
  min-width: 80px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.output {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gif-frames@0.3.0?main=bundled-min&name.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
  <div class="control">
    <label for="file">File</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <label for="frames">Frames</label>
    <input type="text" name="frames" id="frames" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <label for="type">Type</label>
    <select name="type" id="type">
      <option value="image/png">PNG</option>
      <option value="image/jpeg">JPEG</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <label for="extract"></label>
    <input type="button" name="extract" id="extract" value="Извлечь">
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="output"></ul>
```